# minify - Get a timestamped URI to a minified resource using the default Minify install

Tags: minify

I am using Minify and I want a timestamped URI.

The readme.txt suggests this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo Minify_groupUri('css'); ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Minify_groupUri('js'); ?>"></script>
```

but it also says:
'Before including this file, /min/lib must be in your include_path.'

Where is the include_path set??

A.

Comment: Note that Minify is not written by Google, it's simply hosted on Google Code.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your php.ini with

```
include_path = .:/min/lib/:
```